# How to maintain proper number order in mysql auto increment field when delete rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **A** which has a auto increment serial number field **SLNO**. When i insert values in table it will increment automatically like 1,2,3,4... etc. But when i delete a row from the table the order get break. ie, if delete row with serial number 2 then the serial number field will 1,3,4. But I  want to maintain a continuous order like 1,2,3 even delete rows. Is there any way to maintain this order, like using trigger or somthing

Answer (score 2):

A primary auto-increment key is only for uniquely **identifying** a record. Just leave it be.

Don't misuse the primary key as indicator of your record order. If you need specific **order** of your records then use an extra column for that. For instance a `timestamp` column.

If you need a specific order of your records use a `timestamp` column with a default value of `current_timestamp`. That way it will be inserted automatically.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD column inserted_timestamp TIMESTAMP default current_timestamp;
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/240ec/1)

Comment: I just need a specified order for my records, can you suggest a way to do it. i was thinking of using triggers to maintain such a order when delete orders, is this right choice or is there any other easy way

Comment: That ok for date and time But i want to maintain Serial Number like 1,2,3....etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave it as it is.

However, if you do really need, you can "recalculate" the primary key, the index:

```
set @pk:=0;

update 
  your_table
  set pk=@pk:=@pk+1
  order by pk;
```

Answer (score 0):

add a column that will speicfy that is deleted

example:

1 - deleted already

0 - not deleted

and add where deleted = 0 in your select query

```
primary key column 2 column3 ..... deleted
1                                    1
2                                    0
3                                    0
4                                    1
5                                    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing an number of a record would make deletes inefficient. Instead you can rely on existing SLNO indexes you already have, that should be enough for all use cases that come up to my mind.

If you `SELECT whatever ORDER BY SLNO LIMIT ... OFFSET k`, then returned rows have IDs k, k+1, k+2, ...

If you want to get an id of a record knowing its SLNO:

```
SELECT COUNT(SLNO) FROM A WHERE SLNO <= thatnumber
```

If you want to get `thatnumber'th` record:

```
SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY SLNO LIMIT 1 OFFSET thatnumber
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do by alter the table and delete primary key then again create primary key.

But why you need this. If you have use this key as foreign key in other table. Then you lost all the data.

Comment: In my answer I suggest not do this thing he may be lost his data.I know that answer is inefficient.But Technically only this answer is possibly.